# How can I change default python version EMACS 23 uses?

Tags: python, emacs

Trying to change the version of python emacs uses. (OSX10.6)

In Terminal 
   python
brings up the version I've set up in PATH 
But in EMACS it does not.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to look into fixing the environment variable PATH for Emacs which is a little tricky when using Emacs on Mac OS. Just make sure that Emacs' PATH has the same value as PATH in Terminal.app/Bash.  These links should help:

[Accessing OS X / UNIX environment variables in Emacs minibuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261430/accessing-os-x-unix-environment-variables-in-emacs-minibuffer)

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsApp

(cf. Section "Path" and "Alternative Path Solution")

Comment: +1 for pointing this out `Emacs.app on Mac OS X does not inherit the same value of PATH environment variable as on another OS` That was it actually **Emacs.app** doesn't do it right but if you just open Emacs through Terminal, the Python version is correct which would make sense.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way (assuming you are running the GUI version of Emacs), is to choose

```
Options->Customize Emacs->Specific Option
```

and type python-python-command, and fill in the path to the python you want.  Then save for future sessions and you should be good.

I'm really not sure why it wouldn't be honoring the path variable.  The default should be simply "python" (no path).  Maybe you have already set this, or you are changing the command path in your .emacs?  You could look in ~/.emacs and see if you are doing either of those.

Comment: ...I feel extremely nooobish :\ .... I tried setting that to something like so /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python which is where my python binary is. no dice. ...

Comment: It wants the full path to the executable, not just the directory.  So /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python/python might be what you want.  (I'm at work now, so no Mac OSX to check with :(.)

Comment: Well I gave up and switched to Aquamacs. Too bad yasnippets doesn't work in HTML mode in Aquamacs.

Answer (score 1):

try to add this to your .emacs or other config file:

```
(setq python-version-checked t)
(setq python-python-command "python2.7")
```