# emacs 24.3.1 chose python version - missing variable?

Tags: python, emacs

I have different python versions (2.7 and 3) installed on my Linux Mint. Emacs by default (at least in my case) chooses the old version.

How can I choose the newer one?

Trying to change the following variable (as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5952671/3459537 or here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2520486/3459537) doesn't work, since it is absent?! [don't know why...]

```
(setq python-python-command "python3")
```

with this it is the same (found here: http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/python-running-emacs.html):

```
(setq py-python-command "/usr/local/bin/python3")
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's the path to _your_ Python3 install ?

Comment: Then why would you hope `/usr/local/bin/python3` to work ? Have you tried using `/usr/bin/python3` ? Also, there are two python-mode : the (newest but not necessarily better) emacs one and the old Python one. Not sure which one you're using and the variable name may not be the same for both.

Comment: sorry...I used in my case the right path (i.e. the one from my machine; the code snippet was just from the page I referred to); I didn't change my python-mode so I think it is python.el ?! Should I switch to python-mode.el?

Comment: got it! using normal python.el one has just to customize-variable `python-shell-interpreter` to `python3`

Comment: @Coti.Mori., since you solved this yourself, please consider answering your own question (and accepting your answer). That way this question will show up as answered when other users find it.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the hint. I answered my question now. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming one uses normal python.el:

just customize-variable `python-shell-interpreter` to `python3`